# How to create tiles with manage tile cache tool in ArcGIS Desktop from PNGs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a directory of PNGs without any geographic information other than quadkeys which I am converting manually via Python to get the bounding box coordiantes.  For testing purposes I would like to create a single tile in the location that is associated with it.  The steps that I have taken are, create mosaic dataset, apply the extent `(left=-10350185.126039146, bottom=4315940.3650941895, right=-10348962.133586584, top=4317163.357546754)` to the mosaic dataset, tile add individual raster with above coordinate information, then manage tile scheme.

The issues that I am seeing is that the extent properties in the layer and mosaic dataset are auto updating to 0, 255, etc.

What steps need to be taken to visualize the PNG as a managed tile cache with a mosaic data set and my specified extent?

Where should my processing extents be set so that the PNG that I am loading has the correct extent(around Louisiana) it is currently in Australia?  I am using web mercator auxillary sphere for my projection.

Comment: Create world files using that extent.

Comment: @FelixIP what do you mean?